# Horizontal Scrollbar with fullpage.js

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I'm building a website that using css columns for a very long 'about' section. The website also uses fullPage.js. Moving the horizontal scroll bar allows the viewer to being reading many columns of text. This works perfectly on desktop and is a good ux solution.

Problem is the horizontal scrollbar disappears on mobile. I am assuming this has to do with code in fullPage.js and some touchscreen conditional overriding it? Perhaps not though and it's some strange css problem?

You can view the site in development here:

http://mpaccione.com/GET800/index.html#About

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fullpage.js option `normalScrollElements` for the element with the horizontal scrollbar.

From the [fullpage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **normalScrollElements:** (default null) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements. (For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2')

For example:

```
$('#demo').fullpage(){
    normalScrollElements: '#aboutCol'
});
```

And... use the latest version 2.7.4.
The one you are using is quite old.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I will give this a try soon and check back in.

Comment: This worked perfectly. You've answered many of my questions before - thanks for your help and developing a great script.